# Python/Django timestamp including milliseconds

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-2.7

I need to print (and pass to an external API) the current datetime in the following format:

```
DD-MM-YYYY:HH:MM:SS:SSS
```

where the last 3 `SSS` imply milliseconds. I know how to print the current datetime up to microseconds using Python's [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) as in the below `manage.py shell` Django shell session:

```
In [1]: from django.utils import timezone

In [2]: timezone.now()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 5, 15, 26, 10, 71046, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [3]: timezone.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f')
Out[3]: '05-08-2013:15:28:31:647504'
```

How to print the ending `:SSS` part so that the above string becomes:

```
'05-08-2013:15:28:31:123'
```

i.e. displaying milliseconds (using only 3 digits) rather than microseconds?

Comment: It's called milliseconds when it's 3 digits. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the milliseconds separately by dividing the timestamp microseconds by 1000:

```
tznow = timezone.now()
'{:%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S}.{:03d}'.format(tznow, tznow.microsecond // 1000)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> tznow = timezone.now()
>>> '{:%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S}.{:03d}'.format(tznow, tznow.microsecond // 1000)
'05-08-2013:15:36:00.339'
```