# Hiding milliseconds from timezone.now() (In HTML)

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am implementing a feature of `expiring post` so the post will hide in `2 days`, So I am showing user the `remaining time` in post.

Remaining time is showing perfectly BUT It is also showing milliseconds (which i I am trying to hide)

The Output is like :-

> 2 days, 23:43:33.271449

views.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

def blogpost_detail(request,blogpost_id):
    blog = get_objects_or_404(BlogPost,pk=blogpost_id)

    remaining_time = blog.blog_date_added - timezone.now() + timedelta(days=2)

    context = {'remaining_time':remaining_time,'blog':blog}
    return render(request, 'blogpost_detail.html', context}
```

**What i am trying to show as output :-**

I am trying to show like :-

> 2 days 23 Hours Remaining

**What have i tried :-**

- I tried [Python/Django timestamp including milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062031/python-django-timestamp-including-milliseconds) Post's Answer by `dividing 1000` but when i divide `timezone by 1000` like `timezone.now()/1000` then it is keep showing

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

- Then i tried hiding `milliseconds` from `template` by using `time:"h:i a"` like `{{ blog.blog_date_added|time:"h:i a" }}`
  But it is showing nothing as output.
- When i try to add `naturaltime` like `{{ blog.blog_date_added|naturaltime }}` then it is showing the same output.
- When i try to add `timesince` like `{{ blog.blog_date_added|timesince }}` then it is showing :-

> 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'year'

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: This looks like something for the [**`|naturaltime`** template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, When i add `{{ blog.blog_date_added|naturaltime }}` then it doesn't even change the output. It shows the same value

Comment: you need to `{% load humanize %}` first.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have also `loaded humanize`. Otherwise (if i didn't even load) it will raise error like `Invalid filter: 'naturaltime'`

Comment: Furthermore you should also specify the timestamp when the blog is no longer active, so two days after the `blog_date_added`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, You're Right, So, You're saying that i should i make another `field` of `expire_date` so it will keep track of Remaining days and after the expire. (Correct if i am wrong)

Comment: if it is always two days, I would make a property, since then it is calculated based on the `date_added` field, and thus there is no inconsistency possible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Yes , It will always two days and I would never want users to edit that `expire` date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you add a property to your `Blog` when the blog will expire, something as:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class Blog(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    
    @property
    def expire_date(self):
        return self.blog_date_added + timedelta(days=2)
```

In the template we can then work with the [**`|naturaltime`** template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime):

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ blog.expire_date|naturaltime }}
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked.  AND If i try to `set a Boolean to False` so when the expire date will happen than it will turn to `False`. Can i do it like `return self.bounty_date_announced + timedelta(days=7) return is_expired=False` ?

Comment: You can add a property with a boolean, or you can annotate the queryset with `from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q`; `from django.db.models.functions import Now`; `Blog.objects.annotate(expired=ExpressionWrapper(Q(blog_date_added__lte=Now()-timedelta(days=2)), output_field=BooleanField()))` (see https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/annotate-a-condition-as-booleanfield.html) to add an extra field to the `Blog`s that arise form this queryset.

Comment: So, you mean "I can add a property in `models.py` and I can use `ExpressionWrapper` in `DetailView` in `views.py` " ?

Comment: @Lars: one of the two. A property can be used to return `True` or `False`, but not when filtering a queryset, in that case you can filter with `.filter(blog_date_added__lte=Now()-timdelta(days=1))`, and if you want to annotate the items, for example to use it in later filtering, you can annotate these. It probably is more sensical to annotate the queryset where you need this, and do filtering if you want to retrieve only the "active" `Blog` posts.